# Problem updating SQL with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having a peculiar problem with this app. It doesn't update the columns always and there is no rule as to when it will be updated and when will it not.
Seems totally random, and doesn't get me back to admin.php page.

Additionally, when it does change/update the entry in the db it doesn't send a response to Ajax (alert('OK')). Code below:

```
--this is admin.php
```

```html
<div class="update" style="display:none">
 <form method="post" action="adminFunctions.php">
  <div class="input-group">
   <label>new name</label>
   <input class='newNameInput' type="text" name="newName" >
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
   <label>new last name</label>
   <input class='newLastNameInput' type="text" name="newLastName">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn changePerson" name="changePerson">change</button>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

then Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var changeId;
    $('.changeMe').click(function () {
      var el = this;
      var id = this.id;
      var splitid = id.split("_");
      changeId = splitid[1];
      $('.update').css('display', 'block');
    });
    
    $('.changePerson').click(function () {
          var newNameFor = $('.newNameInput').val();
          var newLastNameFor = $('.newLastNameInput').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: './adminFunctions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'changeSth=' + changeId + '&newName=' + newNameFor + '&newLastName=' + newLastNameFor,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == 1) {
                  alert('OK');
                } else {
                  console.log('entry update failed');
                }
            }
          })
        });
});
```

--and adminFunctions.php

```js
if(isset($_POST['changeSth'])) {
    $id = $_POST['changeSth'];
    $newName = $_POST['newName'];
    $newLastName = $_POST['newLastName'];

    changeEntry($id, $newName, $newLastName);
}
function changeEntry ($id, $newName, $newLastName) {
    global $testConn;
    if($id) {
        $query = "UPDATE people SET firstName='$newName', lastName='$newLastName' WHERE id=$id";
        mysqli_query($testConn, $query);
        header('location: admin.php');
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
    header('location: admin.php');
}
```

I'm new at PHP so please forgive the lack of elegance in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget `e.preventDefault()` in your js when you try to send ajax?

Comment: Also type=submit is designed  for input, not for button

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: thanks for the advice guys. @ADyson Thanks man, right now I'm just trying to get basic functionality for this segment working. I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string for other segments to prevent SQL injection

Comment: @AleksandarJocic that's good to hear, although parameterisation is a little bit more secure (there are edge cases where escape_string doesn't protect you) and will also make it easier to read the code, and less likely to introduce unexpected syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/82x5wjq1/3/) for you. I made correct ui example, you need to adapt it on server side. Key change is that you need to pass data, instead of url in ajax via POST.

```
 $('.changePerson').click(function () {
      var newNameFor = $('.newNameInput').val();
      var newLastNameFor = $('.newLastNameInput').val();
        var idFor = $('input[type="hidden"]').val();

      var data = {changeSth: idFor, newName: newNameFor, newLastName: newLastNameFor};
      $.ajax({
        url: './adminFunctions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response == 1) {
              alert('OK');
            } else {
              console.error('entry update failed');
            }
        }
      })
    });
```

**EDIT:**

First thing to highlight is that type='submit' is designed for input nor for the button tag

Second thing, is that data should be transfered via POST method nor url-string. There are few different approaches for getting data from form html. You can use approach from my example with ids/classes or serialize entire form and pass it. (thx @harry)

Comment: Please highlight the neccessary changes such that others can learn from it

Comment: "type='submit' is designed for input nor for the button tag"..actually "submit" is the default value for the "type" attribute in a button tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes . So it's perfectly valid to add it, if somewhat redundant

Comment: @dganenco I removed the action attribute from the form, put the e.preventDefault for AJAX, and as per you recommendation changed the way I pass the data, using your method. So, I'm getting around 95% success rate for changes, which is solid, but why is it not 100%? Is it a "Normal thing" in PHP?

Comment: Also, I didn't understand the var idFor = $('input[type="hidden"]').val(); in your fiddle. I need the id on the element clicked. I used var changeId; to achieve that.

Comment: @AleksandarJocic no it's not normal for things to fail, if you didn't want them to. You need to debug your code and find out exactly what part of the code is failing, and how.

Comment: @AleksandarJocic I added this part because you didn't provided html for getting this id

Comment: right sorry, forgot that part somehow... @ADyson I seem to have gotten the code right and updates entry every time.. So right now, my biggest worry is how is it possible that PHP function doesn't send response to AJAX on success, even if it updates the entry in db. It's like it runs > mysqli_query($testConn, $query); < but doesn't run > echo 1 < one line below.

Comment: @AleksandarJocic the line `header('location: admin.php');` just above `echo 1` tells the browser to go straight to the "admin.php" script and ignore anything else that you output from the current script. Having said that, since you're calling this from AJAX, the browser won't actually do a redirect, so that's a pointless line of code in this context - it only works when you do a full postback, not ajax. How are you determining that it doesn't return the value? Have you looked in your network tools in the browser to see what the result of the ajax call is?

Comment: @AleksandarJocic I just noticed something - can you change `<button type="submit" class="btn changePerson"` to `<button type="button" class="btn changePerson"` please? Since you make this a "submit" button it will submit your form by normal postback when you click it. And it might, or might not, have time to do the AJAX call as well. You don't want them both running, I assume. This could be a cause of the inconsistencies you're seeing. Changing it to `type="button"` disables the default postback behaviour.

Comment: @ADyson MAN! It was the type="button" that made all the difference! That was the last place I looked for bugs. Everything is working perfectly now. I get my entry updated and get a response sent out to AJAX. Thanks a lot Dyson! Much obliged everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are making AJAX request and there is no need serverside redirection. You have to redirect it from JS side if u really want to do so. 
Please Remove `header('location: admin.php');` from your PHP code.

Comment: In addition you should pass data using object via POST method {name: 'ads', id: 1}. I will try to create fiddle for you

Comment: @dganenco You can either create JOSN object and pass it or use serialize function `data: $('.update form').serialize()`  since the form has correct name attributes.

Comment: For sure you can, but for what the reason? Is more simple and clear to pass data if you are using POST

Comment: @dganenco     It's your choice definitely but I would say that using one line function is easier than creating an entire object and finding elements by id and getting the value of them one by one.